# Command line like Angular Cli

Tags: node.js, command, angular-cli

I'would like to create something like Angular Cli with some commands we can create a beaultful scaffold and with others parameters like ng new ng g c ... we can create other components, modules ... etc How Can I search a way to create this or Study the steps to create this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to look at the Schematics feature of the Angular CLI. You can find information about it in this [discussion](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/7627), in this [blog post](https://blog.angular.io/the-past-present-and-future-of-the-angular-cli-13cf55e455f8) and in this [blog post](https://blog.angularindepth.com/creating-your-own-application-template-for-angular-cli-95e22319cc24).